# How can I easily edit files over an SSH connection where I have little control over the server?

Tags: ssh, ftp

Basically what I want is to have the feel of editing files over ssh (or ftp) as if I was working on my local machine.  I'm using SiteGround and it is a shared server.  I can't use git.  Other solutions that would have been nice are the ssh-remote plugin with Visual Studio Code or SSHFS, but I can't get permissions to use these on SiteGround.  Their customer service said the best option was to just download the files I want to edit, and then upload them when finished.  Currently I have FileZilla installed, and that's so far been the easiest way to go about editing files, but still a bit cumbersome.  Is there any way to make this task easier that I'm not aware of?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Isn't `nano`, `vim`, or `emacs` available in the remote shell session?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, nano is available.  I would just prefer to use Visual Studio Code. Mainly so I can easily open several files at once and bounce around between directories.  Also, I haven't used nano/vim/emacs much.  They don't seem as easy to use, but that could be my own ignorance.

Comment: You can have multiple instances of `nano` open simultaneously in an SSH session by using `screen`, and you can learn VIM by playing an RPG now: https://vim-adventures.com/

Comment: Thank you!  I just spent a couple of hours going through some vim tutorials.  I had no idea it could do so much.